# Instanceof and namespaces

Tags: php, instanceof

I am facing an unexpected behaviour trying to use the following:

```
$object instanceof $class
```

1/ PHP 'instanceof' keyword and namespaces work well together, as explained [in the official doc.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php#106882)

2/ Sometimes, however, backslash escaping gives in to more subtle (obscure?) behaviour, as Ben kindly explained in [this](http://forge.benjaminheisig.de/blog/ben/entries/php_assert_is_a_namespaces_incl._escaping) nice post.

Somewhere deep down in my code, y set a couple of dumps as follow:

```
var_dump($object, $class);
var_dump($object instanceof $class);
```

which gives me the following output when running my script:

```
class Tools\Tests\Entity\testObject#226 (2) {
  private $var_one =>
  NULL
  private $var_two =>
  NULL
}
string(36) "Tools\Tests\Entity\testObject"
bool(false)
```

The class of my first dump is strictly the same as the string in my second dump.
However, my instanceof dump returns FALSE. Why ?

I played around with backslashes, with no luck. Maybe I messed up somewhere with namespaces ? The thing is I really don't know how to troubleshoot further down. What should I try ?

Comment: Oh, and I just checked there is no php keyword in my namespace...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can test for instances using namespaces, but use the [fully qualified class name](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php).

For your test I would do this:

```
$class = "\\Tools\\Tests\\Entity\\testObject";
$object = new $class;
var_dump($object instanceof $class); //bool(true)
```

---

You can also test this way using single quotes and not worry about escaping your backslashes and save yourself a few keystrokes.

```
$class = '\Tools\Tests\Entity\testObject';
$object = new $class;
var_dump($object instanceof $class); //bool(true)
```

Comment: Excellent ! This is a combination of slashes I did not try... And it's actually the fix :)

Comment: @mika Glad to help! I test all my instances this way so I don't worry about traversing through the namespace hierarchy incorrectly.

Comment: escaped backslashes is about double quotation mark, as you get `\t` there. Single quotation mark not parsed, so backslashes not need to be escaped.

Comment: @Deadooshka Very good point. I'm so used to using double quotes for most things. I'm going to update my answer to illustrate that in case others come across this in the future.

Comment: @Crackertastic please don't ! In fact I do not use direct assignation of the $class variable, it rather comes from a yaml file that I parsed using the Yaml symfony bundle. Which needs double backslashes in the file. Oh well, if the two options appear, then it's fine ;)

Comment: @mika I didn't change the original answer.  I added a secondary method along side of it.  No worries :)

Comment: Do not use solution. When class is creating it can call some init|construct methods that you don't want to be executed on 'class check'.

Comment: @user1954544 They were working with an instantiated object already. In my answer the instantiation is merely illustrative and to maintain consistency with the OP's target issue.  The answer is still valid.

Answer (score 6):

I use simpler variant

```
var_dump($object instanceof \Tools\Tests\Entity\testClass);
```

Comment: This is more appropriate if you don't have to read the namespace and class from a variable. Also works just using the class name if its namespace has been "used". +1

Answer (score 0):

You should use ReflectionClass to avoid any execution or behaviours you have in\on this model.
Read more aboit ReflectionClass to get more info about class\model we checking.
http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php

```
foreach ($this->modelNamespaces as $namespace) {
    $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($namespace);

    if ($reflectionClass->implementsInterface('common\models\FieldsInCollectionInterface')) {
        // class is implemented by FieldsInCollectionInterface
    }
}
```