# PHP instanceof returns false for true condition

Tags: php, types, instanceof

I'm thoroughly confused as to why php's `instanceof` operator insists that the LVALUE here is not an instance of the defined class when `get_class` says that it is.

```
class WhereIn {
    public function __construct($args) {
        echo "is instanceof: " . ($args[0] instanceof ActiveRecordField) . EOL;
        echo "get class: " . get_class($args[0]) . EOL;
    }
}
```

The output from this method is:

```
is instanceof: 
get class: ActiveRecordField
```

For reference, I'm using PHP 5.6.9.

Comment: My guess is namespace/autoloader, but without a complete example it's hard to tell.

Comment: You're right! It's a namespacing issue. I totally missed that.

Comment: If you post an answer I'll approve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807992/instanceof-and-namespaces

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use namespaces in your code, you need to provide it directly:

```
if ($args[0] instanceof ActiveRecordField) // False

if ($args[0] instanceof \MyCompany\Classes\ActiveRecordField) // True
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Pmpr mentioned you need to provide it directly.

You can include the class like below:

```
use \MyCompany\Classes\ActiveRecordField;

class WhereIn {
    public function __construct($args) {
        echo "is instanceof: " . ($args[0] instanceof ActiveRecordField) . EOL;
        echo "get class: " . get_class($args[0]) . EOL;
    }
}
```