# Php: Php namespacing loses Polymorphic feature of an Object

Tags: php, namespaces, polymorphism

I am doing some project now involving Php namespacing.
But as i go further i notice some irregularity about my design. I loses polymorphism on my objects.

/* First i use interface as higher level of abstraction to my classes */

```
 Interface IFoo {
    function foo();
 }
```

/* Then some implementations */

```
class Foo implements IFoo {
   function foo() {}
}
```

/* So when i do this, its returning true indeed. */

```
$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo instanceof IFoo;
```

/* The problem occurs if i start using namespace to my project */

#IFoo.php

```
  namespace App\Core\Interfaces;

  interface IFoo {
      function foo();
  }
```

#Foo.php

```
  require_once __DIR__.'/IFoo.php';

  namespace App\Core\Models;
  use App\Core\Interfaces\IFoo as IFoo;

  Class Foo implements IFoo {
      public function () {}
  }
```

/*   This will return false instead */

```
 $foo = new Foo();
 echo $foo instance of IFoo;
```

I don't know how to fix the problem, if you can help me thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807992/instanceof-and-namespaces Let me know if that helps.

Comment: very useful sir. Thank you soo much :)